# How did Space Shuttles get off the NASA Crawler?

Tags: rockets, space-shuttle, vehicle-assembly-building, crawler-transporter

The crawler is what transports Shuttles and rockets from the **rocket assembly building to launch pad**.

When the crawler reaches the launch pad, how is the Shuttle transferred from the crawler to the pad?

Answer (score 45):

The crawler carried the shuttle, boosters, and external tank which were mounted on the Mobile Launch Platform (MLP).

[image]

Image source: [Universe Today](https://www.universetoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/discovery_vab.jpg)

The crawler went to the pad, put down the MLP at the launch pad, and crawled away.

This left the MLP, shuttle, boosters, and external tank at the pad.

When the shuttle launched, only the MLP remained.

The crawler came back and got the MLP, and took it to the Vertical Assembly Building so that the stack could be built on it for the next flight.

When the MLP is not on the crawler, it sits on support posts, as shown in this photo where the MLP is at a parking site.

[image]

(personal photo)

The crawler has a [Jacking-Elevation-Leveling (JEL) system](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19760012108/downloads/19760012108.pdf) that allows it to raise and lower the MLP and anything mounted on it. It also keeps the MLP level when the crawler is climbing the slope to the pad.

To pick up the MLP, the crawler lowered the JEL system, drove under the MLP sitting on the support posts, then raised the JEL system to lift the MLP off the support posts.  The reverse happened when the crawler was putting the MLP down on the support posts.

Comment: "When the shuttle launched, only the pad remained" --> perhaps a stupid question, but what happened to the MLP?

Comment: Well, okay, but how does the crawler get out from under all that weight?

Comment: @Rich thanks for the comment, fixing bad phrasing.

Comment: @PeteBecker working on it.

Comment: Don't want to step on @OrganicMarble toes so just a comment here: these might be useful: https://youtu.be/5caQPiRBCAA?t=460 they talk about the JEL (Sorry its SLS, STS), and just a general move video https://youtu.be/kKSC0J1ehFg (I don't know if its a no-no but Spaceflight forum has a crawler thread..?) . Would love to see a simple animation though..

Comment: @blobbymcblobby thanks for the links! The ntrs link is in the answer already.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Sorry, had a hundred tabs on the go and was copy and pasting hurriedly! removed it before the 5minute limit!

Comment: someone made an animation, but skipped over the use of the JEL system: https://youtu.be/oMeXcBk1x-c?t=329

Comment: @blobbymcblobby cool. I like the animation of the orbiter lift. It even shows how it had to be rotated to get the wings to fit through the hole.

Comment: Now it begs a question how the MLP was connected to all the ground supplies, piping etc. :-)

Comment: @filo Apollo-era schematic showing some of the connections here https://i.imgur.com/h1gGRqt.png